# Remove large files on BitBucket

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I have accidentally committed a large file on BitBucket. Cloning the repository on low ram embedded systems causes me an out of memory exception.

I would remove the huge file from the server, or export the history locally to a revision prior the commit, and then push it again to BitBucket.

How can accomplish this?

Regards,
Antonio

Comment: Is this commit the last commit on your branch ?

Comment: No, it was in the middle of the history, but with the below method I solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution from BitBucket:

> You should be able to reset to a commit prior to the one that
>   introduced this file with the command: git reset --hard HEAD~N where N
>   is the number of commits you want to take the head back. Please note
>   that this is a destructive operation, and it permanently deletes the
>   commits, so I would strongly advise that you take a backup before
>   executing this command on the repo. As a next step, you can then force
>   push your changes in the remote repo: git push --f In case this file
>   was pushed many commits back, and you don't want to delete these
>   commits and changes in other files introduced by them, you may also
>   want to consider using BFG to remove this file only from git history:
>   https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ BFG rewrites your history
>   as well, but instead of deleting the commits, you would simply change
>   them to remove this large file from them. Again, a backup is advised
>   in this case as well.

**Edit:** I received an official link from BitBucket/Atlassian staff https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/maintaining-a-git-repository-321848291.html .

Comment: The solution based on filter-branch sub-command is very helpful to rewrite all or parts of the history and deleting a specific file from all commits

Comment: Sure, it solved my problem, but be carefull  at final push. I did not write that you have to issue the command "git push -all", else you will rewrite ONLY the history of the MASTER branch, losing others.